# Allowing socks request for anonymous connections to a private address?

Tags: protocol

I want to ask you how I can allow socks request for anonymous connections. I'm using it with metasploit and socat but its always reject connection. So every time I want to exploit an OS with metasploit and socat, it doesnt work.

You can see it in the picture:

[[image: 1]]

I'm applying what this link says http://securityblog.gr/1246/anonymity-first-tor-metasploit/
but I always run into the problem with Tor that it rejects the connection.

Comment: You could try to setup a Hidden Service on your machine and use it's hostname as rhost..

Answer (score 3):

You can not connect through Tor to a computer inside your own network.
You can only connect to hidden services or to hosts that can be reached from exit nodes.

This is not because it it not *allowed*, but because your Tor client just can't build a circuit that ends inside your own network. It rejects the request because it knows that it can't, so it won't even try.